# Chromium went monochrome in Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, chromium, adblock

The installation of an ad blocker has seriously changed my Chromium (Version 51.0.2704.79 on LinuxMint 17.3 (64-bit)) browser. Now, no pictures show at all, and everything is monochrome. Color appears for a fraction of a second then it's all black, white, and grey, all the time. Removing the ad blocker did not reverse the problem.

How may I restore the original settings for display, without altering other Chromium settings? TY.

Comment: Have you tried to delete your Chrome profile, as a test, you can always backup your current on

Comment: Please advise how to make a backup,  then how to delete it.

Comment: Copy the folder, paste the folder in another location, you don't know how to backup a folder?

Comment: That presumes I know where the profile is.

Comment: You should its [documented](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) on the Chromium website.